# PHP-loader error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

I'm trying to call a PHP file instead of an HTML file as the `templateUrl` for an Angular component.

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-form',
  templateUrl: require('php-loader?./register-form.component.php'),
  styleUrls: ['./register-form.component.css']
})
export class RegisterFormComponent implements OnInit {

...
```

When I run `ng serve`, it throws the following warning:

```
    WARNING in ./app/register-form/register-form.component.ts
40:18-78 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:701:24)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:559:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:506:17)
    at /Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at /Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:60:9
    at tryCatcher (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/pranav/Desktop/angular-first-project/IATutors/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
```

I thought it doesn't matter much, opened localhost:4200, only to find an empty page. I opened the console, where it said:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (register-form.component.ts:18)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/register-form/register-form.component.ts (register-form.component.ts:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb79a8cbd66e1ab28853:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb79a8cbd66e1ab28853:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (environment.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb79a8cbd66e1ab28853:54)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:1242)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb79a8cbd66e1ab28853:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap cb79a8cbd66e1ab28853:25)
```

It might be a problem in my `webpack.config.js`, which I'm not entirely sure if I've formatted correctly:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    "pug-loader?self",
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.php$/,
                loaders: [
                    "html-minify",
                    "php-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I'm not sure what the error is trying to tell me. Why is it looking for module "."? What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real benefit that php conveys as being templates in such cases. The exception says that your app cannot recognize php-load plugin because the app expects ts file prior to php one. I got assumption that the scripts that is building distro is not completely configured for php templates. Please check your dist folder for ts template file which mist be generated from php one or check integration of php-loader.

Comment: `ng serve` doesn't create a dist folder, unless you're talking about a different one. The reason I'm trying to use PHP as the template is because I want to check if values inputted into the form are already in the database and update the page and block form submission accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried to load your php template in this way: `templateUrl: require('php!./register-form.component.php')`?

Comment: Yes, it throws an error saying that a `parseQuery` has to start with a `?`

Comment: That's interesting, because according to the doc [php-loader page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-loader) it must be used as `php!./file.php`. Moreover webpack docs say the same [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html). Maybe something wrong in your webpack config file? Try to use `php!` and in configuration add `query:''` among `test` and `loaders`. Like that: 
`{
                test: /\.php$/,
               query: '',
                loaders: [
                    "html-minify",
                    "php-loader"
                ]
            }`